# How do I get my bot not to log messages that are just embeds?

Tags: discord.js

Currently, I'm making a Discord bot and I implemented a logging feature. When I delete a message from a bot or webhook that contains an embed, it logs it as a deleted message, but with no message content. So, my question is, how do I get my bot not to log deleted messages that contain an embed?

I tried checking if the message had any arguments, and if so to return, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do something like this

```js
client.on('messageDelete', async message => {
    const logChannel = client.channels.cache.get(messageLog)
    if (message.author.bot) return 
    // You can choose to remove this line if you want the if/else statement below to catch the message

    if (message.partial || !message.author) { 
        // logs if the message that is deleted was sent before the bot came online/restarted or if the message contains no author information
        logChannel.send({
            content: `A message was deleted in the <#${message.channel.id}> channel. It's content is unknown.`
        })
    } else { 
        // logs if the message that is deleted was sent after the bot came online/restarted
        const messageContent = message.content || 'No content, likely an embed.' // Captures the content or if no content, states as such.
        logChannel.send({
            content: `The message by ${message.author} shown below was deleted from <#${message.channel.id}>:\n\n${messageContent}`,
            split: true // split the message in case it contains more than 2000 characters
        })
    }
})
```

If you chose to use the `if (message.partial)` part of that code, you will need to make sure you have partials defined:

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
    partials: ['MESSAGE']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
client.on('messageDelete', (message) => {
  // check if there is actually content
  if (message.content) console.log(message.content);
  // or you can just check if there are no embeds (both work):
  if (!message.embeds[0]) console.log(message.content);  
})
```